# Approaching SICP in Clojure instead of Scheme

Tags: clojure, scheme, sicp

I am a third year bachelor student in a software engineering program, and I brought up the idea of reading SICP to an adviser to gain a deeper and more fundamental understanding of the principles behind all this software we engineer.

He suggested not to learn Scheme to complete the book (because it's not as common as modern dialects of Lisp) but to do the exercises in Clojure instead.

It's an already difficult book, if I do attempt the book's exercises in the more modern Clojure, how would that work? For example, I can't find any real solutions, the syntax they teach for Scheme is different, etc.

Answer (score 14):

In my first year at the university the first programming course I took was using SICP (that was 1988). However, I had a similar problem like you: for my own computer (actually a Commodore Amiga), there was no Scheme implementation available at that time, only a different Lisp dialect (I don't remember its name).

However, given the flexibility of Lisp, it was pretty simple to "emulate" Scheme syntax just by adding the missing lisp macros and functions in a few scripts. This was actually enough to implement all the exercises from chapter 1 to 3 required during the course (note that SICP does actually not require the full Scheme stack, a small subset is all you need).

So since Clojure is AFAIK a modern Lisp dialect, I guess you could just do something similar, which gives you the fully free choice to write things either in Scheme or Clojure or a mixture of both.

Of course, solving the exercises directly in Clojure will also be possible, both languages are very similar. More important, SICP **is not about programming language syntax**, it is **about the right use of abstractions** in programming (for example, with functions, data, and objects). So don't think too much of possible syntax problems, these are not in the focus of this book and most probably of minor concern.

Comment: The only issue I foresee is that clojure lacks 1. TCO (`recur` only handles tail *recursion*, not general calls) and 2. the lack of `call-with-current-continuation` which is needed for chapter 4.

Comment: @jozefg: I think if the OP gets himself successfully through chapters 1-3, he will most probably at the point where he won't complain about the syntactical differences between Clojure and Scheme any more ;-)

Comment: @DocBrown consider [edit]ing clarification about chapters 1-3 in your comment above into the answer (and possibly explaining the issues with chapter 4, if you agree with [comment discussing these](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/253799/approaching-sicp-in-clojure-instead-of-scheme#comment510760_253802))

Comment: @gnat: the comment is surely correct, but IMHO a little bit nitty. The important part of my answer is the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question just after finding this site which looks like it is right up your alley (though you may have found it or an alternative in the intervening months): [SICP in Clojure](http://ecmendenhall.github.io/sicpclojure/)